# Istio no matches for kind PeerAuthentication when following mtls migration steps

Tags: security, mtls

I keep getting : `no matches for kind "PeerAuthentication" in version "security.istio.io/v1beta1"` when I'm trying to follow steps describe here :

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authentication/mtls-migration/#lock-down-to-mutual-tls-by-namespace

I looked for this error to understand how I can solve it, but I found nothing.

Does this mean something for someone?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I discovered it's due to the fact that PeerAuthentication is only supported by istio 1.5. As I install Istio 1.4.6 just couple of days before 1.5, I did not realised that. Plus, the fact that it is not mentionned on the doc page is helping.

Comment: Do I need to close the question? How do I do that?